# Many hours-long?

Tags: adjectives

For example, if I wanted to say that the queues at a water park (for example) will be multiple hours long, could I say

There will be hours-long queues?

Comment: 'Hours-long waits' can be found in a Google search, mainly connected with slow Minecraft servers, bad road traffic disruption, high demand for rock concert tickets, etc.

Comment: A fairly common phrase used to describe such situations is *[long wait times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22long+wait+times%22)*

Comment: You are on the wrong site  Try English Language Learners.

Comment: @David Why do you believe that this question is on the wrong site? It's English Language and Usage on my screen

Comment: In answer to your query: The [Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), states that "English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". Thus it is not a site for elementary questions, from *either* native or non-native speakers — [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) exists for the latter purpose. Attempts to pluralize adjectives in compounds of this type (hour-long is acting as an adjective here) are typical of speakers of languages with adjective–noun agreement.

Answer (score 1):

The usual phrase is that there are "hour long queues". The plural would not be needed on the 'hour'.

Queue is a British term for a line of people.

Comment: Actually, Elliot, 'line' is an American term for a queue of people.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't say "hours long" if you mean multiple hours.

Comment: @KateBunting one could, but as you know, we don't say fifty-years-old man (or perhaps you do, I dunno)

Comment: @green_ideas No, I wouldn't use the plural when quoting a figure, but 'hour-long queues' implies that people were waiting for about one hour, so I don't see why one couldn't use 'hours-long' if the wait was of multiple hours.

Comment: @KateBunting The poster would do better advised 1. to use *many* instead of *multiple* here. 2. to rephrase his idea as something like "queues lasting many hours" instead of trying to fit them into an ugly construction. However the purpose of this site is not to help people improve their literary style.